# Take a variable from a serialized data

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, wpallimport

i'm trying to import an csv file to my wordpress installation using wp-all-import 
i have a critical issue my theme maker take value for custom edit as serializeed inputs, 
how ever this input while trying to make imports doesn't accepts (Variables ) as per below

== working code ==

```
a:8:{s:5:"title";s:5:"Cairo";s:19:"wc_course_date_time";s:0:"";s:15:"wc_course_times";s:3:"asd";s:18:"wc_course_language";s:3:"eng";s:17:"wc_course_address";s:5:"lolaa";s:14:"wc_course_city";s:9:"deathnote";s:15:"wc_
course_price";s:6:"123123";s:16:"wc_course_status";s:9:"confirmed";}
```

=== end of working code

i tried to change the code with

```
a:8:{s:5:"title";s:5:"{City_1[1]";s:19:"wc_course_date_time";s:0:"";s:15:"wc_course_times";s:3:"asd";s:18:"wc_course_language";s:3:"eng";s:17:"wc_course_address";s:5:"lolaa";s:14:"wc_course_city";s:9:"deathnote";s:15:"wc_
course_price";s:6:"123123";s:16:"wc_course_status";s:9:"confirmed";}
```

so it can read from the csv file with no joy because s here read it as a string not a variable 
is there a way to make it read variable , i tried serliaze and un-serilaize but catch nothing.

Comment: in `s:5:"Cairo";` the `5` is the string length then try to change it by `s:10:"{City_1[1]";`

Comment: i tried this but it only shows {City_1[1]} inside my website as a text not the variable it self.